# Is there a way to continuously pipe data from Azure Blob into BigQuery?

Tags: azure, google-bigquery, azure-blob-storage, data-pipeline

I have a bunch of files in Azure Blob storage and it's constantly getting new ones. I was wondering if there is a way for me to first take all the data I have in Blob and move it over to BigQuery and then keep a script or some job running so that all new data in there gets sent over to BigQuery?

Comment: May [this](https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/microsoft-azure/google-bigquery/) article could help you.

Comment: Thanks! I did notice that, but I think for their long term integration, I saw their subscriptions (for the amount of data I need to transfer) are 500 bucks a month. I'm aiming to find a consistently free solution (but I'll check to see if that's feasible with this a little more)

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is also not in a database. It's in Azure Blob storage, which Stitch doesn't seem to allow integration for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery offers support for [querying data directly from these external data sources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources): *Google Cloud Bigtable*, *Google Cloud Storage*, *Google Drive*. Not include Azure Blob storage. As Adam Lydick mentioned, as a workaround, you could copy data/files from Azure Blob storage to Google Cloud Storage (or other BigQuery-support external data sources).

To copy data from Azure Blob storage to Google Cloud Storage, you can run [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) (or [Azure Functions](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/04/01/azure-functions.aspx)), and [BlobTriggerred WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to#a-idtriggera-how-to-trigger-a-function-when-a-blob-is-created-or-updated) can trigger a function when a blob is created or updated, in WebJob function you can access the blob content and write/upload it to Google Cloud Storage.

**Note**: we can install this library: [Google.Cloud.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/) to make common operations in client code. And [this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/livedevopsinjapan/2017/01/02/storage-migration-from-google-cloud-to-azure-using-azure-functions/) explained how to use Google.Cloud.Storage sdk in Azure Functions.

Comment: Thanks, Fred! I'll take a look into this to see if this might be a better way to go than the VM! It all depends on cost and speed :)

Comment: Good idea! Note that BigQuery has a limit on total load operations per day, so if you have a very high rate of writes you may need to batch up your loads or use stream insert.

Comment: I'll only be uploading around 100 files a day at most, so that doesn't seem to exceed their limit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything out-of-the-box (on Google's infrastructure) that can accomplish this.

I'd probably set up a tiny VM to:

- Scan your Azure blob storage looking for new content.
- Copy new content into GCS (or local disk).
- Kick off a LOAD job periodically to add the new data to BigQuery.

If you used GCS instead of Azure Blob Storage, you could eliminate the VM and just have a Cloud Function that is triggered on new items being added to your GCS bucket (assuming your blob is in a form that BigQuery knows how to read). I presume this is part of an existing solution that you'd prefer not to modify though.

Comment: Thanks, Adam! I think that's what I'll wind up going with. Yes, this is part of an existing solution that constantly adds these files to Blob and there's no way I can change it to add directly to GCS. I'll get started on that right away :)